Invalid class type <str> for dagster op function
I am running the code below. I have an op and a job but when i do dagster dev I am getting following issue. There is another op which loads data from a table and here I want to put this data into another table. The data frame is being loaded as I can see with dagster preview. The load ops is giving the output as dataframe.
@op
def save_df_to_db(db: resource.sql_resource, dataframe, custom_table_name: str):
    log=get_dagster_logger()
    log.info("Connecting to db", custom_table_name)
    with db.get().begin() as con:
        dataframe.to_sql(custom_table_name, con, if_exists='append', index=False)
    ...

Job definition
@job
def start_day_job():
delivery_location=import_ops.get_location()
import_ops.save_df_to_db(dataframe=delivery_location, custom_table_name="Delivery_Location")

import_schedule=ScheduleDefinition(
    job=start_day_job, cron_schedule="0 7 * * 2-6",execution_timezone="Europe/Zurich"
)

However I am getting this error.
in @job start_day_job received invalid class type str for input  
(custom_table_name) in op invocation "save_df_to_db". 
Must pass output from previous node invocations or inputs 
to composite function as inputs when invoking nodes during composition`

How do I resolve this error?
I have tried the following.

Passed as custom parameter.
Passed as config schema

Still same issue.

This is because literal values, in this case the pd.DataFrame and the str custom_table_name cannot be passed directly to the operator. Instead, they have to either be returned as an Out from another operator, or as a configuration value. See the following example for how to specify a RunConfig the the table_name.
import pandas as pd
from dagster import op, job, Out, Definitions, Config, RunConfig
from dagster_duckdb import DuckDBResource


class SaveTableConfig(Config):
    custom_table_name: str


@op(out=Out(pd.DataFrame))
def create_dataframe():
    data = {
        "Column1": [1, 2, 3],
        "Column2": ["A", "B", "C"],
        "Column3": [True, False, True],
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df


@op
def save_df_to_db(dataframe: pd.DataFrame, db: DuckDBResource, config: SaveTableConfig):
    with db.get_connection() as conn:
        dataframe.to_sql(
            config.custom_table_name, conn, if_exists="append", index=False
        )


@job(
    config=RunConfig(
        ops={"save_df_to_db": SaveTableConfig(custom_table_name="Delivery_Location")}
    )
)
def start_day_job():
    df = create_dataframe()
    save_df_to_db(dataframe=df)


defs = Definitions(
    jobs=[start_day_job],
    resources={
        "db": DuckDBResource(
            database="my.duckdb",
        )
    },
)

In this example I opted use DuckDB to confirm things are working as expected. Cheers.
